# Permission Denied on Cabal Update

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm getting a "permission denied" error when I try the following command:

```
$ cabal update
```

I'm on Mac OS 10.6. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: are you sure you're running it as the correct user?  Have you somehow set in your `~/.cabal/config` (or wherever the settings are kept on OSX) that it should do it as a global install?

Also check the permissions of where the tarball will be downloaded to:

```
$ ls -l ~/.cabal/packages/
$ ls -l ~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/00-index.*
```

This should show that your user is indeed allowed to download the list of packages.

Comment: I reinstalled GHC and its all working fine now, but thanks for the help!